# React Native: Populating FlatList from fetched JSON data & filtering data to render a particular icon depending on the data type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am having difficulty figuring out how to use the RN  component with data that I am fetching form an API.

The **fetched data** looks like so:

```
fetchDataActionCreator {
"isFetching": false,
"items": {
  "user1": [
    {
      "from": "home address",
      "to": "destination address",
      "cost": "8.95",
      "tripNo": "1234",
    },
    {
      "from": "random address",
      "to": "home address",
      "cost": "10",
      "tripNo": "1235",
    },
  ]
  "user2": [
    {
      "from": "home address",
      "to": "destination address",
      "cost": "8.95",
      "tripNo": "4321",
    },
    {
      "from": "random address",
      "to": "home address",
      "cost": "10",
      "tripNo": "4322",
    },
  ]
}
```

}

And here is the **action creator** function in my Redux structure that is retrieving the JSON data:

```
function fetchDataActionCreator(users) {
return function(dispatch) {
  dispatch(requestDataActionCreator());

  const reqs = users.map(user => {
    /* [{from, to, cost}] */
    return getData(users.userId.toLowerCase(), user.number);
  });

  return Promise.all(reqs).then(allHistory => {
    /* [{from, to, cost}] */

    const res = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < allHistory.length; i++) {
      res[users[i].userId] = allHistory[i];
    }

    dispatch(receiveDataActionCreator(res));
  });
};
```

}

Below is the code for the **component**

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View, Fragment, FlatList, ListItem, Icon, RefreshControl} from 'react-native';

renderItem = ({
    item: { to, from, cost},
  }) => (
    <ListItem title={}>
      <Fragment>
        <View>
            <Icon name={}/>
        </View>
        <Text>To address: {to}</Text>
        <Text>From address: {from}</Text>
        <Text>Cost: {cost}</Text>
      </Fragment>
    </ListItem>
  );

  keyExtractor = ({ tripNo }) => tripNo;

  filterTrips = () => {

  };

class History extends Component {
  render() {
    const { isLoading, onRefresh } = this.props;

    const filteredTxs = this.filterTxs();
    return (
      <View>
          <FlatList
            data={filteredTxs}
            keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            refreshControl={<RefreshControl refreshing={isLoading} onRefresh={onRefresh} />}
          />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    history: state.fetchDataActionCreator,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(History);
```

I am having difficulty with these things in particular:

- a: successfully passing in the JSON data into the ListItem component
- b: filtering the data in such a way that a particular icon will be displayed based on whether the `from:` or `to:` item happens to be matched with the `"home address"` value. If the value of `from:` is `"home address"` then I want to render an icon named `leaving`, and if the value of `to:` is `"home address"` I would like to display an icon called `returning`
- c: for this particular component, I only want to display the data for `user1`

Any guidance on how I might achieve this would be very appreciated as I am quite new to React/React Native.